# the .NET sdk is not showing up after installation

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

I have installed the .NET SDK version 5.0.401 and even after restarting my computer it doesn't show up when I look it up on my command prompt using dotnet --list-sdks.

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`? Does the folder `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401` exist?

Comment: There is not output. But the folder exists.

Comment: Do you run dotnet.exe in `C:\Program Files\dotnet` or in `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`? `dotnet --info` can be used to determine this.

Comment: I have now run it and still nothing shows up